# Bet on behalf of someone living in a country where betting is illegal

Tags: international, gambling

Let's say I have a friend living in a country like Albania where sports betting is illegal. I tell him he can send me money and I will bet for him in my country (for example Italy), where betting is legal. If he wins, we agree that I keep part of the win for me.

Is he committing a crime in Albania?  Am I committing a crime in Italy?

Comment: What the country?

Comment: For example Albania and Italy

Comment: @IginoBoffa I have edited that information into your question.  I have also changed the wording of the actual question to clarify it.  If I have got your intent wrong, please [edit] the question to fix it.

Comment: @MartinBonner No it's ok, thank you

Comment: This question can't be answered in a generic way for any pair of countries as it depends on the exact laws of the two countries in question. It is possible you would be breaking Albanian law but not Italian, which means you might get extradited, or they might just arrest you next time you visit Albania.

Answer (score 3):

> Is he committing a crime in Albania?

It would help if you posted the statutes that regulate or prohibit betting, since the terms thereof would shed light on the legal definition (aka *prima facie* elements) of betting and/or the legislative intent behind those statutes. Absent that information, your description reflects that most certainly the Albanian is committing a crime.

The Albanian's conduct matches --at least-- the *ordinary* meaning of betting: he is not disbursing (or promising to disburse) money merely for fun or leisure, but for the prospect of possibly profiting from an uncertain event of which he officially has no control. Doing it through a third party located in another country changes nothing in this regard.

> Am I committing a crime in Italy?

The Italian might be considered an *accessory* of that conduct being classified as criminal in Albania. Thus, facilitating activity that is prohibited in Albania could turn out to be problematic even for the Italian.

Furthermore, even if betting is legal in Italy, the Italian might be in trouble under the laws of Italy if taking money (without the requisite license) from someone else to make bets constitutes *unauthorized business* of gambling. The condition that the Italian would retain a portion of any profits makes the *business* (or *for-profit*) element quite evident.